# Check if CheckBox is checked, which is not in view of ListView

Tags: android

I have ListView, which contains a TextView and a CheckBox.
Now I am able to get text in the TextView, which is not in view of TextView, but I am not able to get if the CheckBox, which is not in view of ListView, is checked or not.

Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this can be done if u can get your text information from adapter by using 
Adapter myadapter=MyList.getAdapter ;
View rowview=myadapter.getView(i,null,MyList);
now find textview by its id in rowview after that to chewck whether check box is checked or not then u can maintain booleon type array in custom adapter and maintain evrey checkbox state.
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked hundreds times.

you cant check the state of those views because they does not exist - the listView create temporary views to present on the screen when needed. the solution is to save the checkBoxes state into another source of data (eg an array) when checked/unchecked and in your custom adapter decide the checkbox's state using this array like- `if (suppose to be checked) checkbox.setChecked(true) else checkbox.setChecked(false)`